# Remote host Identification has changed

Tags: ssh

I try to copy a file to my remote server with scp.

```
sudo scp atlassian-jira-6.4-x64.bin username@ip-adress:/
```

When I execute, I get the error:

```
WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!
    IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
(fingerprint)
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
RSA host key for IPADRESS has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

So I removed the known_hosts file from ~/.ssh and tried the command again. But still there is this message coming up. Where do I need to modify my files then besides the .ssh folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh remote host identification has changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840012/ssh-remote-host-identification-has-changed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `known_host` file under following directory using `vim` editor on terminal.

```
 vi     /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts OR  /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

delete all lines using `dd` command and save the `known_host`s file using `:wq!` and restart your sshd service.

```
service sshd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if the problem is repetitive, you can try to use this method.

Add the following lines to the beginning of the SSH configuration file.

```
Host *
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
   UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

or for a specific host

```
Host localhost
        HostName localhost
        UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
        StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```