# How to get rid of "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED" message

Tags: ssh

I have several virtual machines installed on my computer, to which I connect via ssh:

```
ssh vm1@localhost
```

or

```
ssh vm2@localhost
```

So every time I connect to different vm I need to edit my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file in order to get rid of: “`WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!`” message.

Is there any way to trust automatically all VMs on localhost?

Comment: How should those commands connect to different systems? They all connect to your local host.

Comment: @arkascha — Presumably through port forwarding.

Comment: @Quentin Even so, why should that port forwarding behave different depending on the account name?

Comment: @arkascha — It doesn't. The change is behaviour is due to one VM being shutdown and another one being started up … so the port forwarding goes to a different host.

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox, so when I need `vm2`, I'm shutting down `vm1` and vice versa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh remote host identification has changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840012/ssh-remote-host-identification-has-changed)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your configuration (e.g. ~/.ssh/config) you can trash the known hosts for a specific hostname:

```
Host localhost
        HostName localhost
        UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
        StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

[credit](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/how-to-disable-ssh-host-key-checking.html)

Answer (score 11):

You can try modifying the `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Deleating all inside the file is an option**, you can do it with nano or your favorite editor. Eg.:

```
nano ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Try again the connection, it should work

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/yourkey.pub vm1@localhost
```

**nevertheless it would be a good practice if you only delete the row associated to the conflict.

Comment: Thank you, your solution fixed the issue I was facing.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable host checking specifically for `localhost` by setting `NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost` to `yes` in `~/.ssh/config` as follows.

```
NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost yes
```

Note that this does not work when connecting to `localhost` on another machine through jump hosts.

Alternatively, you could still achieve host checking like normal by defining a distinct `HostKeyAlias` for each host.
This has the added benefit of working over jump hosts, too.
The following example configuration of `~/.ssh/config` demonstrates this.

```
Host vm1
  HostName localhost
  HostKeyAlias vm1.localhost

Host vm2
  HostName localhost
  HostKeyAlias vm2.localhost
```

This is recommended for this situation by the [ssh_config manpage](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config).

> HostKeyAlias
> Specifies an alias that should be used instead of the real host name when looking up or saving
> the host key in the host key database files and when validating host certificates.  This
> option is useful for tunneling SSH connections or for multiple servers running on a single
> host.

Answer (score 2):

```
ssh-keygen -R YourIPorDomainName
```

With this, `~/.ssh/known_hosts` will be updated along with `.old` backup.

Answer (score 0):

For bitbucket users faced this issue after May 2023.

Do the following in the git terminal:

```
ssh-keygen -R bitbucket.org && curl https://bitbucket.org/site/ssh >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

More details in [the guide](https://bitbucket.org/blog/ssh-host-key-changes).