# Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch (fingerprint c8:81:b6:00:a7:55:eb:09:d5:8e:f6:3b:ee:47:7b:5f does not match for "Server IP")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-server-2012-r2, ubuntu-18.04

From my rails application, when I tried to dowload a file from one our **Window Server** using `gem 'net-scp'`.**(The rails application is running on ubuntu 18)**

```
Net::SCP.start(ENV["IP_ADDRESSS"], ENV["USER_NAME"], :password => ENV["PASSWORD"]) do |scp|
      scp.download(ENV["75_SERVER_PATH"], Rails.root.join('public/output_json.json').to_s)
    end
```

But the server is not allowing us to access the file and I getting the follwing issue,

```
Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch (fingerprint c8:81:b6:00:a7:55:eb:09:d5:8e:f6:3b:ee:47:7b:5f does not match for "Server IP")
```

Comment: You can call [remember_host!](https://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v2/api/classes/Net/SSH/HostKeyMismatch.html#M000305) and retry to bypass the exception.  Would not recommend in production but it might help you troubleshoot. [`ssh-keygen -R ENV["IP_ADDRESSS"]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21795390/5399937) seems to have worked in the past.

Comment: @Tom it is working perfectly thanks